# Is it possible to create a dictionary of an entity and refer to it in the data layer

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, dictionary

I have what is in effect a lookup table in my database upon which my entity model has been based.  I would like to refer to this as I respond to OnPropertyChanged events for a particular entity.  Given that there could be hundreds of requests to this table I figured that it would be more efficient to create a dictionary from that lookup table and refer to that instead.  To that end I have a partial class for mty entities to which I have added the following.

```
Imports System.Data.Entity

Partial Public Class FireTrackerEntities : Inherits DbContext

Private _defUnitsOfMeasurement As Dictionary(Of Int16, string)
Public Property DefUnitsOfMeasurement As Dictionary(Of Int16, string)
    Get
        Return _defUnitsOfMeasurement
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Dictionary(Of Int16, string))
        _defUnitsOfMeasurement = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    CreateDictionaries()
End Sub

Private Sub CreateDictionaries()
    Dim ft As DbSet(Of FireTrackerModel.ExtinguisherType)
    For Each p In ft
        DefUnitsOfMeasurement.Add(p.ExtinguisherTypeId,p.DefaultUnitOfMeasurement)
    Next
End Sub
```

The code compile but in the entity where I wish to refer to this dictionary I can't see it.  So Is this entirely the wrong approach or have I missed something?

Thanks

Comment: This feels like a wrong approach *somewhere* but it's hard to pinpoint it without knowing the bigger picture. In the first place, having entities with `OnPropertyChanged` doesn't seem right. (If you're still in the `ObjectContext` API, IMO using these events should be left to EF internals alone.) Further, why "hundreds of requests to this table"? Anyway, it may certainly be a good idea to cache this lookup table in one way or another, but it's not clear to me where and how you address these data.

Comment: Firstly this is EF6.0 using DB Context.  The entity in which I wish to refer to this dictionary implements INotifyPropertyChanged and one of those properties should determine the value of several others each time it is set (which as I said could be several hundred times (the underlying tables acts as an inventory list)).  I had thought that I might be able to create this dictionary as a property of the data model's entities and thus be able to call it from any of them, but it seems not to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Would you not just do something like this to create a `Dictionary`:

```
myDbContext.SomeEntities.ToDictionary(Function(e) e.Id)
```